# Add linker options to Eclipse CDT Autotools project

Tags: c++, eclipse, linker, autotools, eclipse-cdt

I'm not sure if I'm completely missing the point here, but I can't find a place to add linker options in the Eclipse CDT plugin for an Autotools project.
I want to link a static library with a -l option
I was expecting to find them in a tab with a name like 'linker' after going to

```
Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings
```

Where do I get to the linker options?

If I can't do it like this then which config or make file can I edit manually to achieve the same result (linking a static library)

--edit--

I came across a recommendation that I should add this to my configure.ac

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([DEPS], [libavutil >= 6:0.8.10-1 libavformat >= 6:0.8.10-1 libavcodec >= 6:0.8.10-1])
```

I tried this but this doesn't persuade autotools to tell the linker to link the appropriate libraries. Have I missed something???

--edit 2--

My Makefile.am was the default as generated by the CDT new project wizard for an autotools project.

```
SUBDIRS=src
```

The Config.ac file was as per default too...

```
dnl Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.

AC_PREREQ(2.59)
AC_INIT(HelloWorld, 1.0)


AC_CANONICAL_SYSTEM
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE()

AC_PROG_CXX

AC_CONFIG_FILES(Makefile src/Makefile)
AC_OUTPUT
```

I tried adding in a line to the Config.ac that looked like this:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([libav], [libavutil >= 6:0.8.10-1 libavformat >= 6:0.8.10-1 libavcodec >= 6:0.8.10-1])
```

I put this line just after the 'AC_PROG_CXX' line

I then added the following to my Makefile.am...

```
HelloWorld_CPPFLAGS = $(libav_CFLAGS)
HelloWorld_LDFLAGS= $(libav_LIBS)
```

The file HelloWorld.cpp is just a quick test that should report the libavformat version

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C" {
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}

int main(void) {
int avVer = avformat_version();
printf("libavformat version number: %d", avVer);
return 0;
}
```

This is all managed by the eclipse CDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article has helped clarify things:
http://aquamentus.com/autoconf_tutorial.html

I was putting some things in the wrong places.
A separate Makefile.am is used for the program as it is in the src subdirectory.
This needed to go in the Configure.ac as sugested before

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([libav], [libavutil >= 6:0.8.10-1 libavformat >= 6:0.8.10-1 libavcodec >= 6:0.8.10-1])
```

This generates two variables to use in the Makefile.am, these are...

```
$(libav_CFLAGS)
$(libav_LIBS)
```

The top level Makefile.am just needs to point to that directory as it did before...

```
SUBDIRS=src
```

The linker flags for the program are handled in the src/Makefile.am file with something like the following...

```
bin_PROGRAMS=HelloWorld
HelloWorld_SOURCES=HelloWorld.cpp
HelloWorld_CPPFLAGS = $(libav_CFLAGS)
HelloWorld_LDFLAGS= $(libav_LIBS)
```

Comment: Good, I'm glad you got it all figured out in the end!

Comment: Me too, thanks for the help. I'm now learning finding my way around the pitfalls of libav. :-D

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the relevant `-l` flag to `AM_LDFLAGS` in `Makefile.am`; e.g.:

```
AM_LDFLAGS = -l<library name>
```

It is considered a good idea to add the corresponding code in `configure.ac` to ensure portability to other systems.

Comment: Can you explain exactly where/how to add this to my configure.ac file?

Comment: This link should help you out: https://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/autoconf/finding.html

Comment: Perhaps I am doing something really badly wrong... When I change my Makefile.am file nothing changes. It doesn't attempt to add my linker commands at all.

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to need to post your Makefile.am.